# form in popover not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and I want to create a form in a popover. I've done this but I can't type in the textfield of the form. Does anyone know why?

***update** It's inside a modal. Outside the modal it works but inside it doesn't...

***update2** Almost there I think. When I open modal and popover, I can't type in the textfield. After I close modal, popover is still open and then I can type in the textfield. So there must be some z-index between the textfield and popup. Real sloppy but I tried `input{z-index:9999;}` but it didn't work

```
<a href="#" class="add_nr" data-nummer-id="nr_1" rel="popover">


<div id="add_number" class="popover">
    <div class="addnr" id="nr_1">
        <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Artist">
            </div>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Number">
            </div>
            <a href="#">cancel</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">add number</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>




$(function(){
        $('.add_nr').on('click', function(event){
            var $this = $(this);
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.add_nr').not($this).popover('hide');
            $this.popover('show');

        }).popover({
            trigger: 'manual',
            placement: 'bottom',
            content: function(e) {
                var $this = $(this),
                nr_id = $this.data('nummer-id');
                return $('#' + nr_id + '.addnr').html();
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: I would guess an issue with your CSS where some element is overlapping and therefore blocking the input.  There's not enough information in your question to tell, you'll need to provide more.

Comment: give code of your class popover,addnr and form-inline.
there must some conflict within the styles you have added in your css class.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that it's in a Modal. If I put it outside modal it works, but inside it doesnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a Modal is launched it maintains focus upon itself, preventing the elements in the form from obtaining focus.  A simple workaround would be to disable the listener when the modal launches:

```
$('body').on('shown','.modal', function() {
  $(document).off('focusin.modal')
});
```

Comment: I checked all the CSS and couldn't find any interactions between `form, input` and the modal classes, so I figured it must be coming from JS.  A quick search of **".on"** in **bootstrap-modal.js** turned up the `focusin.modal` listener, and sure enough that was it.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming to this issue (popovers with forms not working modals) and who are using Bootstrap 4, you can fix this by using `data-modal="false"` on the button/controller that opens the modal. E.g.:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new" data-focus="false">
```

If you're opening your modal using JS, you can pass in a `focus` option. Full docs on the options [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/modal/#options)